# Selector for labels which only refer to a checkbox

Tags: html, css, input, label

I'm wondering if there is a CSS selector to select any `label` which refers to an input type `checkbox`.

```
<label for="checkbox_1">First checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="1">
```

so what works easily:

```
label[for='checkbox_1'] { /* styles */ }
```

but then I have to repeat this for every label which refers to a checkbox.
I would like to do something like:

```
label[type='checkbox'] { /* styles */ }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: In CSS4 this probably will be natively possible with `label:has([type=checkbox])`. Can’t wait for that.

Comment: Oh wait, if they are not nested, this can be done by the `+` selector: `[type=checkbox] + label`. But this only works if `label` and `input` are the other way round…

Comment: Okay I did some more research: [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) the comments suggest a future syntax like `label:has(+ [type='checkbox'])`. But [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbnnt7w3/) demonstrates the use when they are the other way round.

Comment: @Xufox thanks for your research. So basically my markup is, that label and input are seperated a wrapper div. Like: `<div><label></div><div><input></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector that selects all LABELS with the type attribute starting with the word "checkbox":

```
label[type^='checkbox']
```

More information about attribute selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `^=` instead of `=|` then?

Comment: Still `^=` instead of `=^`.

Comment: You're right. I fixed it. I was looking at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp ... I gotta stop going to w3schools :\

Comment: But it’s also `^=` there. `|=` selects the beginning of a hyphen separated list.

Comment: Right. w3schools had no mention of the hyphen.

Comment: I know this selector, but my in reality I don't have a `checkbox` string in all my `for=""` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with pure CSS, as far as I know. You do have a couple of options for workarounds, though:

**The [attribute^='value'] selector**
This will work if your labels actually start with the same identifier/word when associated with checkboxes, similarly to the code example you provided.

*Example*:

HTML

```
<label for='chckbx'>Foobar</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='chckbx_1' value='1' />
```

CSS

```
label[for^='chckbx']{/* styles */}
```

---

**Writing your HTML in a certain way**
This will work if you already have your `<label>`s and their associated `<input />`s in their own container, or if you can modify your HTML to be that way. The trick is to select the checkbox element's container via CSS, and then style it's child `<label>`s.

*Example*:

HTML

```
<div class='checkboxContainer'>
    <label for='foo'>Foobar</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='foo' value='1' />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.checkboxContainer > label{/* styles */}
```

---

**Using JS**
I can write a simple code example to do this with JavaScript(/jQuery), if you want me to.